# Windows Phone 8.1 App cant find Client Secret Key

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to setup my WP8.1 app to use PushSharp Notifications.

I need to specify the CLIENT SECRET KEY.  All MSDN documentation on this is outdated and i cant find it anywere.

I have created my app and can see all other info e.g. SID etc

thanks

Edit: Added dashboard image
[image]

Comment: You will get it in dashboard

Comment: @Archana lol. I have looked everywhere. can you be more specific? ive added an image of my dashboard. Nothing there!

Comment: Under services -> pushnotification->wns/mins  Click on Live Services in that page

Comment: @archana thanks found it!